# gif won't show while loading PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, css, loading, gif

I have a HTML/PHP page which takes about thirty seconds to load.
It is structured as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- some <link>s and <script>s -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
  </script>
  <style>
     .loader {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
        }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
<?php
//data retrieval from a DB, with some time-consuming processing (spelling check using a large dictionary...)
?>

 </body>
</html>
```

I would like to load an animated gif while the page loads.
There are lots of tutorials online (using CSS and/or JQuery). The most common way of doing it is to insert the gif right below the opening `<body>` tag and trigger it while the page loads using JQuery. Above I used the method recommended by Mr Knutson (http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/).

I have tried severeal methods, but I never managed to show the gif **while** the page loads.
The gif always appears on the loaded page, after thirty seconds  of nothing.

Am I trying to do something wrong? Any tips?

Comment: can you provide some of this codes, and why 30 seconds that is a LOT of time

Comment: Actually, if you comment out the database time consuming php code, the page should load much faster, the idea is then to transform that code into an ajax call that should trigger on document load